# Can I show a loading sign while the page is reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET page that users save data on. When they click the save button the data is saved in vb and the page reloads to update the current data on the page, with the new data they just saved. Some of the db queries on this page take a while and the users try to do other things on the page while it is reloading.

Can I show the progress bar front and center somehow? I've been looking around and can't really find anything. I am not doing a postback either. I am reloading the page to execute the queries that are done on pageload.

I am looking for a javascript, jquery, or vb solution.

Comment: You can show an interstitial progress page that redirects to the results page immediately / after a delay. Alternately, use AJAX to perform the action and provide progress updates.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using jquery to load the page asynchronously, and show an animated gif to show that it is loading. Once the page loads in jquery, you can remove the aniamted gif / refresh the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

**$('<img src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif"')
.appendTo(#someID)**

...<ajax call to load page>...

 **$('#someID').find('img').remove();**      


});
```

Answer (score 1):

People usually solve this by placing a loading animation instead of a progress bar, because in order to know the actual progress of the page you have to use unnatural complex mechanisms that I don´t currently understand (or don´t even exist).

You can fire a simple javascript event on form submit which adds a class to the BODY and removes it after load (if it is an ajax query, otherwise it gets removed by it self). These sample events are for non-ajax forms:

Like this (pure JavaScript):

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
   document.body.className += ' t-loading';
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('FORM').submit(function(){
       $(document.body).addClass('t-loading');
});
```

Then you add a CSS like this

```
BODY.t-loading { background:url(loading.gif) center center no-repeat; }
BODY.t-loading * { visibility:hidden; }
```

[You can look for a free loading icon in google.](http://goo.gl/nSf5F)

Comment: The mechanisms definitely exist, but you are right about it being complicated.  The GMail file upload progress bar is a good example.  Basically, it keeps checking with the server asynchronously to see how much of the file has uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I use  *bootstrap* , and this simple progressbar

```
$("main").prepend( '<div class="progress fixed-top">  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-warning w-100"></div></div>');
```